# How to get the weekend holiday logic

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to come up with logic for holidays. Our company policy is 12/24 and 12/25 are both holidays , but when 12/25 falls on a sunday the preceding Friday and day after Monday are Holidays. For example in 2016 12/25 was a Sunday , i want to create a new column with a WORKDAYFLAG as Y and N. Please see the sample code, here the workdayflags are Y, but they need to be N. If christmas in on SATURDAY then the preceding FRIDAY AND SATURDAY should have value N for workdayflag, please advice. I cant think what it is called , but connecting with the same table based on condition, CASE WHEN HOLIDAYNAME='CHRISTMAS' AND DAYNAME='SUNDAY' then connect ...

```
    CREATE TABLE WORKDAYFLAG (
CALENDAR_DATE DATE,
DAYNAME VARCHAR(10),
WORKDAYFLAG VARCHAR(1)
);
INSERT INTO WORKDAYFLAG (CALENDAR_DATE, DAYNAME,WORKDAYFLAG)
VALUES(‘12/25/2016’,SUNDAY,N)
VALUES(‘12/24/2016’,SATURDAY,N)
VALUES(‘12/23/2016’,FRIDAY,Y)
VALUES(‘12/26/2016’,MONDAY,Y)
```

So far i tried using LEAD and LAG functions and CASE statement , but not sure how to connect , like ( CASE WHEN HOLIDAYNAME='CHRISTMAS' AND DAYNAME='SUNDAY' THEN .........................

Thanks

Comment: PLease tag your question with the database you are running: oracle, postgresql, sqlserver...?

Comment: Is this Microsoft SQL Server dialect?

Answer (score 0):

```
select CASE DATEPART(WEEKDAY,CALENDAR_DATE)
          WHEN 7 THEN DATEADD(DAY, -1, CALENDAR_DATE)
          WHEN 1 THEN DATEADD(DAY, 1, CALENDAR_DATE)
          ELSE CALENDAR_DATE
      END
FROM
    WORKDAYFLAG
```

to update the flag :

```
update WORKDAYFLAG
set WORKDAYFLAG = CASE when DATEPART(WEEKDAY,CALENDAR_DATE) in ( 1, 7 ) then 'N'
         else 'Y' END
```

Answer (score 0):

How I would solve this?  With one-shot statements that UPDATE my calendar table once for all.

```
-- Logic for all years on which Christmas falls on Sunday
UPDATE WORKDAYFLAG 
SET WORKDAYFLAG='N'
WHERE YEAR(CALENDAR_DATE) IN 
    (SELECT YEAR(CALENDAR_DATE) 
     FROM WORKDAYFLAG 
     WHERE DAY(CALENDAR_DATE)=25
       AND MONTH(CALENDAR_DATE)=12
       AND DATENAME(WEEKDAY,CALENDAR_DATE) = 'Sunday'
     )
   AND MONTH(CALENDAR_DATE)=12 AND DAY(CALENDAR_DATE) IN (23,26)
;

-- Logic for all year on which Christmas falls on Saturday
UPDATE WORKDAYFLAG 
SET WORKDAYFLAG='N'
WHERE YEAR(CALENDAR_DATE) IN 
    (SELECT YEAR(CALENDAR_DATE) 
     FROM WORKDAYFLAG 
     WHERE DAY(CALENDAR_DATE)=25
       AND MONTH(CALENDAR_DATE)=12
       AND DATENAME(WEEKDAY,CALENDAR_DATE) = 'Saturday'
     )
   AND MONTH(CALENDAR_DATE)=12 AND DAY(CALENDAR_DATE) IN (24,25)
;
```